# AWS StepFunction: Adding new column to the summary

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, state-machine-workflow

In AWS StepFunctions, we could view all the executions along with their statuses like below.
Is it possible to add custom columns here?  We want to add new column 'email' in this tab by processing and filtering CloudWatch logs for this specific execution. Could you please describe the steps to achieve this?

[image: StepFunction Executions Summary]